# How to Insert and edit from the grid-view on run time using resource file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on resource files. I can now read resx file and get it populate the data into the grid-view. now here is my question now,

On a run time, i want to be able to edit the columns and also be able to click empty columns and click save to save my changes. How do i do that. please help me as i have tried many examples and it didn't work.

my code below,

```
    private void btnNewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
            for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();

                string font = Between(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
                string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
                string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");

                string[] row = new string[] { oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(), oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(), font, datestamp, commentVal };
                Gridview_Output.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable);
            oDataSet.WriteXml(PathSelection);
        }
```

Save button(the user must be able to save the file created or edit to any location (C drive))

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Resource Files";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "resx";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Save Resource Files (*.resx)|*.resx";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //nere i need the user to save to any location he want not textbox.
                txtOutputfile.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;                    
            }
            //oDataSet.Tables.Add("Data");
            oDataSet.WriteXml(PathSelection);               
            versionIncrement();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully added ");
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question (the link is beneath the tags) and try to format your code into something readable. I was going to do it for you, but man this is a mess... ;)

Comment: am trying to format but it is failing

Comment: I have formatted my code now. very clean now

Answer (score 1):

See if the below code helps.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UpdateResource.aspx.cs" Inherits="UpdateResource" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Update Resource</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Enable Disable all TextBoxes when Header Row CheckBox is checked.
            $("[id*=chkHeader]").bind("click", function () {
                var chkHeader = $(this);

                //Find and reference the GridView.
                var grid = $(this).closest("table");

                //Loop through the CheckBoxes in each Row.
                $("td", grid).find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {

                    //If Header CheckBox is checked.
                    //Then check all CheckBoxes and enable the TextBoxes.
                    if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                        var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                        td.css({ "background-color": "#00000" });
                        $("input[type=text]", td).removeAttr("disabled");
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                        var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                        td.css({ "background-color": "#FFF" });
                        $("input[type=text]", td).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                });
            });

            //Enable Disable TextBoxes in a Row when the Row CheckBox is checked.
            $("[id*=chkRow]").bind("click", function () {

                //Find and reference the GridView.
                var grid = $(this).closest("table");

                //Find and reference the Header CheckBox.
                var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);

                //If the CheckBox is Checked then enable the TextBoxes in thr Row.
                if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                    var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                    td.css({ "background-color": "#FFF" });
                    $("input[type=text]", td).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                    var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                    td.css({ "background-color": "#00000" });
                    $("input[type=text]", td).removeAttr("disabled");
                }

                //Enable Header Row CheckBox if all the Row CheckBoxes are checked and vice versa.
                if ($("[id*=chkRow]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkRow]:checked", grid).length) {
                    chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
                } else {
                    chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbResources" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbResources_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Width="275px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DataGrid ID="gridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Groove" ForeColor="#333333" Width="500px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%= ++indexNum %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="English Word">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Key") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Translated Word">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Value") %>'
                            BorderStyle="Groove" disabled="disabled"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTrans" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Value") %>'
                            Enabled="false" BorderStyle="Groove"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <%--<asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='editresource.aspx?key=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Key") %>&file=<%=cmbResources.SelectedItem.Text %>&id=<%=indexNum - 1 %>'>
                            Edit</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>--%>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle ForeColor="#333333" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="verdana" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:DataGrid>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public partial class UpdateResource : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int indexNum = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //string resourcespath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "App_GlobalResources";
            //DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(resourcespath);
            //foreach (FileInfo filInfo in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            //{
            //    string filename = filInfo.Name;
            //    cmbResources.Items.Add(filename);
            //}
            //cmbResources.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Resource File"));
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\D1956\Desktop\ResourceEdit", "*.aspx");
            foreach (string file in filePaths)
            {
                string[] f = file.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                cmbResources.Items.Add(f[f.Length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void cmbResources_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbResources.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            string filename = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "App_GlobalResources\\" + cmbResources.SelectedItem.Text;
            Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            ResXResourceReader RrX = new ResXResourceReader(stream);
            IDictionaryEnumerator RrEn = RrX.GetEnumerator();
            SortedList slist = new SortedList();
            while (RrEn.MoveNext())
            {
                slist.Add(RrEn.Key, RrEn.Value);
            }
            RrX.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            gridView1.DataSource = slist;
            gridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "App_GlobalResources\\" + cmbResources.SelectedItem.Text;
        string filename1 = filename.Remove(filename.Length - 5);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filename);
        XmlNodeList nlist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)gridView1.Items[i].FindControl("chkRow");
            if (chkItem.Checked)
            {
                XmlNode childnode = nlist.Item(i);
                XmlNode lastnode = childnode.SelectSingleNode("value");
                TextBox txtTran = (TextBox)gridView1.Items[i].FindControl("txtTrans");
                lastnode.InnerText = txtTran.Text.ToString();
            }
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(filename1 + "_1" + ".resx");
    }
}
```

You may have to edit the **!IsPostback** part.